# Unable to create topic using kafka AdminUtils.createTopic

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

Exception in thread "main"

```
kafka.common.KafkaException: Failed to parse the broker info from zookeeper:

{"listener_security_protocol_map":{"PLAINTEXT":"PLAINTEXT"},"endpoints":["PLAINTEXT://localhost:9093"],"jmx_port":-1,"host":"localhost","timestamp":"1506322454462","port":9093,"version":4}
```

What is the possible solution for this?

I have checked everywhere but nothing seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

Check kafka version on broker and client, probably you use outdated client.

Comment: Whenever I am trying to create toipc I get "EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client sessionid 0x15eb7cf1d750009, likely client has closed socket" at Zookeeper terminal. And using dependencies  "org.apache.kafka" % "kafka_2.11" % "0.10.0.1" build with sbt